# Quick way to compute $\langle n^{'}l^{'}m^{'}|r^k|nlm \rangle$, $k \in I$; $|nlm\rangle$ is $H$ atom eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hydrogen, spherical-harmonics

I want to compute quickly (using maybe some scaling arguments) $\langle n^{'}l^{'}m^{'}|r^k|nlm\rangle$, where $k \in I$. $|nlm \rangle$ is the eigenfunction of the Hydrogen atom ($H$).

Example:

Quickly compute $\langle r\rangle_{nlm}$ and the likes.

Some quick help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Quick help as in "my assignment is due in ten minutes and I need you to solve this for me"? The question is valid but we don't really operate on those sorts of timescales.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Nope nothing of that sort. You can take all the time you need. "Quickly" in the sense compute faster!

Comment: Closely related: [Table of matrix elements of powers of r for radial functions in H atom](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64551/)

Comment: You can use the analytic formula for the radial matrix element in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/table-of-matrix-elements-of-powers-of-r-for-radial-functions-in-h-atom/747794#747794), combined with the fact that the angular integration gives $\delta_{l’l}\delta_{m’m}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer gives an analytical approach for *diagonal matrix elements*.

First of all, since $r^k$ is spherically symmetric you can immediately integrate the angular parts:
\begin{equation}
\left< n' l' m' | r^k | n l m \right> = \left< n'l \right\| r^k \left\| nl \right> \delta_{l',l} \delta_{m',m},
\end{equation}
where $\left< n'l \right\| r^k \left\| nl \right>$ is called the reduced matrix element.

**Diagonal matrix elements: expectation values of $r^k$**

Diagonal matrix elements $\langle r^k \rangle = \left< nl \right\| r^k \left\| nl \right>$ can be calculated with a combination of the Hellmann-Feynman theorem and Kramers' relation without the need to perform any integral explicitly.

The [Hellmann-Feynman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem)  is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{dE}{d\lambda} = \left< \psi(\lambda) \right| \frac{\partial H}{\partial \lambda} \left| \psi(\lambda) \right>,
\end{equation}
where $\left|\psi(\lambda) \right>$ is a normalized ket for all $\lambda$. In this case you take $\lambda = l$ (note that $n=n(l)$) for $k=-2$ and $\lambda = Z$ for $k=-1$. Here $l$ is the angular momentum quantum number and $Z$ the atomic number.

[Kramers' relation](https://physics.drexel.edu/~tim/open/ryd/node2.html) is a recursion relation from which all other $\langle r^k \rangle$ for integer $k$ can be found. It can be derived (see link) from the radial Schroedinger equation of the hydrogen-like atom and is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{k}{4} \left[ \left( 2l + 1 \right)^2 - k^2 \right] a_0^2 \langle r^{k-2} \rangle - Z \left( 2k + 1 \right) a_0 \langle r^{k-1} \rangle + Z^2 \frac{k+1}{n^2} \langle r^k \rangle = 0,
\end{equation}
where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius. Note that this relation by itself gives all $\langle r^k \rangle$ for $k>-2$ since $\langle r^0 \rangle = 1$.

**Off-diagonal matrix elements**

For the off-diagonal matrix elements, I looked in the 8th edition of [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://www.mathtable.com/gr/) (page 817) for an analytical expression of the relevant integrals, but none is given there. Likely, there are no analytical expressions for the off-diagonal matrix elements. This is also confirmed by the paper linked in [the answer of Emilio Pisanty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/217228/41958).

Comment: Fortunately I looked up Griffiths yesterday. The problem was given in an exercise. Either way thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sbp Can you point to the exact problem you found? Does it give the expectation values only, or also the off-diagonal matrix elements?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Kramers' relation is Problem 6.34

Comment: OK, so purely diagonal elements, so not a full answer to the question as posed.

Comment: *Likely, there are no analytical expressions for the off-diagonal matrix elements.* Actually, there is one. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/table-of-matrix-elements-of-powers-of-r-for-radial-functions-in-h-atom/747794#747794) for an analytic formula for the general radial matrix element.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a messy calculation for the most general case, and a direct attempt based on special-functions properties of the Laguerre wavefunctions is likely to simply falter and die in the not-quite-right forms of the integrals.

These matrix elements are calculated in terms of recursion relations in

> Matrix-element calculations for hydrogenlike atoms. M.L. Sánchez, B. Moreno, and A. López Piñeiro. [*Phys. Rev. A* **46** no. 11, 6908 (1992)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.46.6908)

and the authors provide software to calculate them in

> HYDMATEL: a code to calculate matrix elements for hydrogen-like atoms. M.L. Sánchez and A.López Piñeiro. [*Comput. Phys. Commun.* **75** no. 1-2, 185 (1993)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0010-4655(93)90174-B)

with the software available at

> HYDMATEL: a code to calculate matrix elements for hydrogen-like atoms. [Computer Physics Communications Program Library, Id ACLO v1.0](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/ACLO_v1_0.html)

under the [CPC standard license](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/cpc/cgi-bin/licenceCheck.pl?catid=aclo_v1_0).

Comment: See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/table-of-matrix-elements-of-powers-of-r-for-radial-functions-in-h-atom/747794#747794) for an analytic formula for the general radial matrix element. I derived it using an integral formula I found on functions.wolfram.com. I have no idea how long that integral formula has been known.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the eigenstates of the hydrogen atom can be separated into a tensor product of angular momentum eigenstates and a radial solution, the [Wigner-Eckart theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem) helps to calculate the matrix element of any tensor-like operator (a scalar as $r^k$ is a trivial case) between states of the form $|lm\rangle$. The rest is an integral over the radial components that can be calculated using the fact that the Laguerre polynomials (contributing to the radial component) form an orthonormal basis in $L^2$. Obviously, some integrals may be complicated to work out, but that is a different matter.