# Is there a list of hydrogenic transition matrix elements online?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, hydrogen, matrix-elements

Calculating transition matrix elements can be difficult, and I have found myself needing to use hydrogenic electric dipole transition matrix elements a fair bit.

$$\mathbf{r}_{nlm}^{n'l'm'}=\langle\psi_{nlm}~|~\mathbf{r}~|~\psi_{n'l'm'}\rangle$$

Is there any online source that gives the nontrivial matrix elements above (for hydrogen obviously)?

Comment: I never worked my way through Salpeter and Bethe's book on one- and two-electron atoms, but that might may give some pointers.

Comment: There is a [list of spectroscopic databases](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-databases) from the NIST, including a [database for many types of atoms](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html) that includes many (though not all) transition probabilities.

Comment: [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/table-of-matrix-elements-of-powers-of-r-for-radial-functions-in-h-atom/747794#747794) provides an analytic formula for the radial matrix elements of $r^k$. You can derive your matrix elements from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a partial answer, I took the advice of @JonCuster and pulled the following equations from *"Quantum Mechanics of One- & Two- Electron Atoms"* by Bethe and Salpeter. All results are in C.G.S units.

The sum of dipole transition intensities for initial state $(n,l,m)$ and final states $(n',l+1,m')$, where $m'$ runs over the three allowed values ($m'=m-1,m,m+1$), is given by

$$\sum_{m'}|\mathbf{r}_{n,l,m}^{n',l+1,m'}|^2=\frac{l+1}{2l+1}\left(R_{n,l}^{n',l+1}\right)^2$$

Similarly, we have for final states with $l'=l-1$,

$$\sum_{m'}|\mathbf{r}_{n,l,m}^{n',l-1,m'}|^2=\frac{l}{2l+1}\left(R_{n,l}^{n',l-1}\right)^2$$

Here, the symbol $R_{n,l}^{n',l'}$ represents the radial overlap between hydrogenic states $(n,l)$ and $(n',l')$. A consequence of the above equations is that the lifetime of a state does not depend on the magnetic quantum number $m$.

The closed-form expressions for the radial overlap matrix elements in their full generality are highly complicated. Quoted once again from Bethe and Salpeter (who themselves quote W. Gordon), for $n'\neq n$,

$$\begin{align*}
R_{nl}^{n',l-1}&=\frac{(-1)^{n'-1}}{4(2l-1)}!\sqrt{\frac{(n+l)!(n'+l-1)!}{(n-l-1)!(n'-1)!}}\frac{(4nn')^{l+1}(n-n')^{n+n'-2l-2}}{(n+n')^{n+n'}}\times\\
&\times\left\{F\left(-n_r,-n_r',2l,-\frac{4nn'}{(n-n')^2}\right)-\left(\frac{n-n'}{n+n'}\right)^2 F\left(-n_r,-2,-n_r',2l,-\frac{4nn'}{(n-n')^2}\right)\right\}
\end{align*}$$

where $F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,x)$ is the hypergeometric function, $n_r=n-l-1$ and $n_r'=n'-l$ are the radial quantum numbers for the two states.

**EDIT:** I could almost swear that I stumbled upon a random website in which you could type in whatever transition matrix element you wanted and it would spit it out (presumably from a pre-calculated table). It had an enormous amount of dipole **and** quadrupole transition matrix elements (for sure electric, maybe magnetic?). I really don't think I was dreaming when I came across it, but now I'm not too sure since I can't find it anywhere. I think it may have been associated with [the authors of this paper](http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv3i13p117.pdf), but I'm not too sure.

---

[[1]](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-4104-8) "Quantum Mechanics of One- & Two- Electron Atoms" by Bethe and Salpeter

[[2]](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19293940807/epdf) (German) W. Gordon: Ann. d. Pys. (5) **2**, 1031 (1929) - radial overlap integrals are calculated here. They are of course expressed in units of the bohr radius.

Comment: [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/table-of-matrix-elements-of-powers-of-r-for-radial-functions-in-h-atom/747794#747794) provides an analytic formula for the radial matrix elements of $r^k$. The matrix elements in this question can be derived from this.