# Radial wave function matrix elements

Tags: wavefunction, atomic-physics, dipole-moment

For hydrogen atom radial wave function is the analytic form of the matrix elements,
$$\langle n'\ell'|r^k|n\ell\rangle,$$
known? I am especially interested in $k=-2$ and $k=-3$.

**Notation:** 
$$|n\ell\rangle=2^{\ell+1} e^{-\frac{r}{a n}} \sqrt{\frac{(-\ell+n-1)!}{a^3 n^4 (\ell+n)!}} \left(\frac{r}{a
   n}\right)^\ell L_{-\ell+n-1}^{2 \ell+1}\left(\frac{2 r}{a n}\right)$$
and,
$$\langle n'\ell'|r^k|n\ell\rangle=\int_0^\infty 2^{\ell^\prime+1} e^{-\frac{r}{a n^\prime}} \sqrt{\frac{(-\ell^\prime+n^\prime-1)!}{a^3 n^{\prime4} (\ell^\prime+n^\prime)!}} \left(\frac{r}{a
   n^\prime}\right)^{\ell^\prime} L_{-\ell^\prime+n^\prime-1}^{2 \ell^\prime+1}\left(\frac{2 r}{a n^\prime}\right)2^{\ell+1} e^{-\frac{r}{a n}} \sqrt{\frac{(-\ell+n-1)!}{a^3 n^4 (\ell+n)!}} \left(\frac{r}{a
   n}\right)^\ell L_{-\ell+n-1}^{2 \ell+1}\left(\frac{2 r}{a n}\right)r^kr^2dr$$

Comment: [This paper](http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv3i13p117.pdf) has a formula for the case when $n=n’$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/table-of-matrix-elements-of-powers-of-r-for-radial-functions-in-h-atom/747794#747794) for an analytic formula for your matrix element. Note: For $k=-3$ some matrix elements are infinite.